# Шифрование данных для доступа к БД

Tags: c#, шифрование

Возник вопрос касающийся шифрования:есть строка, содержащая в себе данные подключения к бд (логин, пароль пользователя, порт и тд). Стоит ли их как-то зашифровывать в коде и расшифровывать во время запросов к базе или как-то по-другому защищать? Пишу код на c#.

Читал на форумах, что стоит пользоваться симметричным и ассиметричным типами шифрования. Например,у пользователя есть публичный ключ, а затем с его помощью расшифровывается симметрично зашифрованная строка (или как-то так этот принцип объясняют...)

Comment: С клиентских приложений в бд не ходят. Вместо этого делают API сервер. БД не должна быть доступна на внешку вообще. Иначе оно всё легко и просто взламывается. Независимо от того, что вы там придумаете с шифрованиями.

Comment: Такие вещи вообще не хранятся в коде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В случае десктопного приложения - шифрование не поможет. Ну или поможет от уровня "посмотрел в конфиг, а там пароль". Пользователь с правами администратора в любом случае сможет достать пароль пользуясь отладчиком. Возможное решение - использовать Windows auth в случае доменной сети и SQL Server. Тогда воровать будет нечего.
2. В случае web - шифрование почти не имеет смысла, т.к. защищает от случая "кто-то залез на сервер и утащил оттуда конфиг". Может быть при совместном доступе к серверу, когда другой пользователь может зайти на сервер, почему-то может посмотреть конфиг, это имеет какой-то смысл, но сценарий imho нереальный.

Так что в общем случае - не стоит. Просто не храните пароль в исходниках, подкидывайте его в момент деплоймента, и все будет хорошо.

Comment: Отличный ответ. Благодарю за такое подробное описание. Пока что, у меня работает в формате "десктопное приложение - локальная БД (на xampp, phpmyadmin)". Позже, хочу перенести БД на арендованный сервер. Хотелось уточнить - что значит "в момент деплоймента"? Нашёл вот такую статейку, но не уверен, то ли это: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/deploying-database-projects

Comment: @Frehzy по деплойментом подразумевался процесс заливки на сервер. В вашем случае - подкидывайте имя и пароль при сборке десктопного приложения, перед отдачей пользователям. в конфиге в исходниках храните только тестовые/локальные имя и пароль